# How can I render a menu item as a span (or other elements) instead of a <a>?

Tags: 7, navigation

I'm using Drupal 7 with the Bootstrap base theme, and I'd like to create a second and third level of drop-down. I tried using the special_menu_links module but nothing happens. I also tried what suggested on https://www.drupal.org/node/143322, but that doesn't work either.

How can I render a menu item as a span (or other elements) instead of a `<a>`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Special menu items](https://www.drupal.org/project/special_menu_items) module.

> User can create a new menu item and place either  or
>    to the Path field, without quotes.

Also, you can look at another handy module called [Menu attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) which allowed you to have control over menu link attributes.

Both modules use [hook_menu_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7.x) to adjust the changes to the menu item, you can take look at the module's code to understand how it works exacitly if you are interested.